# How to do APN as sever side in IOS with php server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

i have some doubt based on APN as server side.i had used third part tool as server side as parse but i dint know how to do as own server,could any one clarify?

Thanks advance

Comment: You need to post some code, or what have you tried so far.

Comment: if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

Comment: actually i had done client side what are the thing is require but i don't know how to do server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent tutorial for the same -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Uses PHP & Swift.

How does the backend work --> (Already explained in the tutorial)

You have to create the PushNotification certificate from developer portal, when you create that you also have a private key attached.
They together form the PEM, which marks authorisation.

Post that, you simply call the apple push servers to send a notification.

This is different for development and distribution though.

Comment: But bro i m looking of obj c only

Comment: It has Objective C + Php.. You do need a backend to send push notifications.

Comment: Note: Updated for Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3, and Swift 2.2 on 04-03-2016

Comment: if i click that link its based on swift

Comment: could u explain how to do php as in server side

Comment: Its pretty simple, they already have a sample code on the tutorial, use that.

Comment: in server side how would insert the certificate?

Comment: Upload the pem file in the same directory as your php code, it will access it. Check the tutorial for detailed explanation for how to create a pem file.

Comment: Yeah sure i understood the logic.but i don't much more about server side thats only i m struggling with server side.

Comment: Actually,i have one more question if i will install xampp dmg then what i do as server side plz could explain ?

Comment: Its detailed bro, you should ideally follow some good tutorial. It will take a while to figure out everything.